# Get site ID from attachment url?

Tags: customization, multisite

I created a function which gets the metadata video length from the selected attachment. I use this together with a plugin called `multisite-global-media` which lets me share media from a site to all other sites in the multisite network. But selecting a video from this media site will break my function, as I am not able to pull the metadata from attached media from the other site except if I use the `switch_to_blog` function.

But I need to determine if the selected media is from the current site or from the media site.

This is what I am working on:

```
switch_to_blog($attachment_site);

$attachment_id = attachment_url_to_postid( $_POST[ 'background-video' ] );
$video_meta = get_post_meta( $attachment_id , '_wp_attachment_metadata', true ); 

restore_current_blog();

if( isset( $_POST[ 'background-video' ] ) && $video_meta['length'] >= 1 ) {
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'slide_duration', $video_meta['length'] );
}
```

What I need to do is to get the `$attachment_site` somehow.

Any idea how?

EDIT:

```
if( isset( $_POST[ 'background-video' ] ) ) {
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'background-video', $_POST[ 'background-video' ] );
}
```

Comment: Is `$_POST[ 'background-video' ]` just an attachment ID? Where's it coming from? You're probably going to need to send the site ID with the POST request, so the code before posting is probably more relevant here.

Comment: $_POST[ 'background-video' ] is the attachment URL, which I then convert to an attachment id/post id. I tried finding more relevant code to post here but I am not sure what I found is very relevant. Posted it above!

Comment: Where are you getting the URL from?

Comment: @JacobPeattie I get it from a input field on the custom post type.

Comment: Does the user just type it in, or is it being selected from the media library?

Comment: Selected from the media library, rest is done via Javascript: `$('#background-video').val(media_attachment.url).trigger("change");`

Comment: Can you log `media_attachment` and see if it has the site ID included? You'd need the `multisite-global-media` plugin to make that information available at this stage.

Comment: Just tried to log it to the console. `undefined`

Comment: Are you logging it at the same place? It's obviously not undefined because you're getting the URL from it. Regardless, I have to say, this is ultimately a 3rd-party plugin question about how that plugin works, so isn't really on-topic here. I suggest you ask the plugin author for guidance.

Comment: Sorry, was a typo. Yes it logs, but only the video-url that it points to `#background-video` and sets as a value for the input.